# Different pixel values in ArcGIS Desktop and R?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcmap, r

I am using the NAFD _NACP open source data set available at

https://daac.ornl.gov/NACP/guides/NAFD-NEX_Forest_Disturbance.html

As noted in the metadata, a raster for 2010 has 6 classes (Data gaps, Open Water, Forest Cover, no Forest Cover etc). When I open this raster in Arcmap, I see that only these 6 values are present. Also the attribute table has only these values.

However, when I open this raster in R (reading it using raster() in raster package), the min and max values are 0 and 255.

Why is there this difference between ArcGIS Desktop and R?

Also, if I have to reclassify this raster to keep only pixel values=3 (Forest Cover), should I recalssify everything below and above 3 as NA using recalssify(nafd 2010 raster,c(0,3,NA,3,255,NA). I tried this and when I export the result, the raster becomes a float 32 bit unsigned type (the original is 8 bit unsigned).

Why is this happening?

I have tried to specify in the writeRaster() that the dataType=INT1U, but this does not do anything.

Comment: What values are present in the raster in R? Are there any values apart from 0-5 and NA?

Comment: it should be `write(r,"r.tif",datatype="INT1U")`, lower-case, not `dataType`. And that should probably be a separate question!

Comment: This is how some USGS products are distributed and are displayed in ArcMap via a lookup table thus, accounting for the difference between the software. The data range is still 8-bit with just certain values attributed. I would just kill the spurious values associated with the 8-bit (0-255) data range. In R, something along the lines of:  r[r > 4] <- NA The remaining values are then: 1=water, 2=non-forest, 3=forest, 4=forest-disturbance with 0=data-gaps which, if present, could also be turned into NA's. Apparently in the time-integrated disturbance maps, 15-40 is reserved for disturbance year.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference in minimum and maximum between ArcGIS and R, data is the same. Try this:

```
library(raster)
r <- raster('path/to/NAFD-NEX_Forest_Disturbance raster')
r <- setMinMax(r)
r
```

For big rasters, min and max values are related to data type, as 0-255 for an unsigned 8 bits raster.

Comment: This is actually not the case. Some USGS products store the full 8-bit range but only have certain "live" pixels associated with a lookup. NLCD is a good case of this where, if you symbolize under the value field in ArcMap you will see all 255 unique values but under the default field there are only certain values associated with the real classes.